# How can I count the number of non-blank lines in a varchar?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a Notes column (varchar) in a table and I'd like to count the number of non-blank lines.  If there are no erroneous CR/LF's then it's simple...but the third party app allows users to enter the data however they want.

```
DECLARE @Notes VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Notes = 
'Note 1
Note 2
Note 3
Note 4
Note 5'

SELECT @Notes AS 'Notes', LEN(@Notes) - LEN(REPLACE(@Notes, char(10), '')) + 1 AS LineCount


SET @Notes = 
'Note 1
Note 2
Note 3
Note 4
Note 5

'

SELECT @Notes AS 'Notes', LEN(@Notes) - LEN(REPLACE(@Notes, char(10), '')) + 1 AS LineCount


SET @Notes = 
'Note 1
Note 2

Note 3
Note 4
Note 5'

SELECT @Notes AS 'Notes', LEN(@Notes) - LEN(REPLACE(@Notes, char(10), '')) + 1 AS LineCount
```

Is there a simple way to count the non-blank lines so all of these examples return 5?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it like this. See, your technique only counts the lines, but you need to be able to investigate the content of the lines, and for that you must first break the content of the string into lines.

A simple way to do it is using a string splitting function.
For this demonstraiton I've chosen an xml based function described in Aaron Bertrand's article [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings), but you can replace it with any other function you want.

First, create the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
GO
```

Now the tests:

Test 1

```
DECLARE @Notes VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Notes = 
'Note 1
Note 2
Note 3
Note 4
Note 5'

SELECT @Notes AS 'Notes', 
       COUNT(Item) As LineCount
FROM dbo.SplitStrings_XML(@Notes, char(10))
```

Results:

```
Notes   LineCount
Note 1
Note 2
Note 3
Note 4
Note 5      5
```

Test 2

```
SET @Notes = 
'Note 1
Note 2
Note 3
Note 4
Note 5

'

SELECT @Notes AS 'Notes', 
       COUNT(Item) As LineCount
FROM dbo.SplitStrings_XML(@Notes, char(10))
```

results:

```
Notes   LineCount
Note 1
Note 2
Note 3
Note 4
Note 5
          5
```

test 3

```
SET @Notes = 
'Note 1
Note 2

Note 3
Note 4
Note 5'

SELECT @Notes AS 'Notes', 
       COUNT(Item) As LineCount
FROM dbo.SplitStrings_XML(@Notes, char(10))
```

Results:

```
Notes   LineCount
Note 1
Note 2

Note 3
Note 4
Note 5      5
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for all the cases in the question

**Note:** If there are blank lines at the beginning or at the end then I remove that first and then I remove the blank lines in between.

```
DECLARE @Notes VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Notes_1 VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Notes_2 VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Notes = 
'Note 1
Note 2

Note 3
Note 4
Note 5'

--replacing blank line at the beginning or at the end only
set @Notes_1 = reverse(stuff(reverse(@Notes),1,patindex('%'+char(13)+'[^'+char(10)+']%',reverse(@Notes)),''))  
--replacing blank between
set @Notes_2=(SELECT replace(@Notes, char(10) + char(13), ''))

if ((len(@Notes_2)-len(@Notes_1))<=3) 
 begin
  set @Notes = reverse(stuff(reverse(@Notes),1,patindex('%'+char(13)+'[^'+char(10)+']%',reverse(@Notes)),'')) 
 end 
 set @Notes=(SELECT replace(@Notes, char(10) + char(13), ''))

SELECT @Notes AS 'Notes', LEN(@Notes) - LEN(REPLACE(@Notes, char(10), ''))+1  AS LineCount
```